# To avoid manual files errors how to code dynamic datatype of a column check in spark/scala

Tags: apache-spark

We are getting lot of manual files which we need to validate the few datatypes before process the data-frame. Can someone please suggest how can I proceed on this requirement. Basically need to write one spark Generic/common program which should work for many files. if possible please send more detail on this email id as well pathirammi1@gmail.com.

Comment: I'm sorry but SO isn't a coding platform, I suggest that you go through the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [how to ask questions on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if your files have records with delimiter seperated (like csv file). If yes, you could very well read it as a text file and split the records based and delimiter and process it.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDDFromCSVFile {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={

    def splitString(row:String):Array[String]={
      row.split(",")
    }

    val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val rdd = sc.textFile("randomfile.csv")

    val rdd2:RDD = rdd.map(row=>{
     val strArray = splitString(row)
      val field1 = strArray(0)
      val field2 = strArray(1)
      val field3 = strArray(3)
      val field4 = strArray(4)
      // DO custom code here and return to create RDD
    })

    rdd2.foreach(a=>println(a.toString))
  }

}
```

If you have non-structured data then you should use below code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDDFromWholeTextFile {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("alice.txt")
    rdd.foreach(a=>println(a._1+"---->"+a._2))

  }
}
```

Hope this helps !!
Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Thanks for quick reply naveen. Yes I am getting csv manual files but having different different structure. In that I need to check few numeric fields contains only numeric data or not and mandatory fields contain values or not. For this requirement If we can do with one generic program then can use for all the files.

Comment: Do you have the header in a csv file which represents column names, if yes then you can check the column name and verify if the data is in numeric? Certainly When you have columns you should use DataFrame not RDD.

Comment: yes..I have the header in my file. but columns name are different in different files which I need to check.. if possible can you email me the details to my email id pathirammi1@gmail.com